# Error when call node app.js, [node js socket io]how to fixed it?

Tags: node.js, linux, websocket, socket.io, centos7

Error when call node app.js, [node js socket io]how to fixed it ?

1. `cd /home/admin/web/my-doamin-name/public_html`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install --save express socket.io`
4. `node app.js`

...............................................................

But still show this error

```
/home/admin/web/my-domain-name/public_html/app.js:9
        consloe.log('start server on port :3000');
        ^

ReferenceError: consloe is not defined
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/my-domain-name/public_html/app.js:9:2)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1257:10)
    at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

...........................................................

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('https').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    consloe.log('start server on port :3000');
});
```

.......................................................

index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>HELLO WORLD</body>
</html>
```

When i tried to access `mydomain.com:3000` it's not work, how can i do ?

Comment: `consloe.log` => `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to use the http module when you are using express.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log("The server is listening at port: 3000")
})
```